# Prop is possibly undefined error in Vue 3 setup

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

The `console.log('test',props.list)` works well.
But `props.list.map` doesn't work.
Here is the error message.

[image]

And here is the code of the component
How can I fix this error?

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
      <div v-for="column in columnList" :key="column.id" class="col-4 mb-4">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card h-100 shadow-sm" >
                <img :src="column.avatar" :alt="column.title">
                <h5>{{column.title}}</h5>
                <p>{{column.description}}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">enter</a>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
import { computed, defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

export interface ColumnProps{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    avatar?: string;
    description: string;
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ColumnList',
  props: {
    list: {
      type: Array as PropType<ColumnProps[]>,
      require: true
    }
  },
  setup (props) {
    const columnList = computed(() => {
      console.log('test',props.list)
      return props.list.map(column => {
        if (!column.avatar) {
          column.avatar = require('../assets/default_avatar.jpg')
        }
        return column
      })
    })
    return { columnList }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the `list` prop is populated by an async call.  If so, the computed runs at least once before `props.list` is defined.  When it's undefined, it has no `.map` method.

Provide for that situation by returning an empty array:

```
setup (props) {
  const columnList = computed(() => {
    if (!props.list) return [];         // ✅ Return an empty array if undefined
    return props.list.map(column => {
      if (!column.avatar) {
        column.avatar = require('../assets/default_avatar.jpg')
      }
      return column
    })
  })
  return { columnList }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think, the only bit missing is a typo in the `required` option.

Change

```
props: {
    list: {
      type: Array as PropType<ColumnProps[]>,
      require: true
    }
  },
```

to

```
props: {
    list: {
      type: Array as PropType<ColumnProps[]>,
      required: true // <-----  CHANGE TO "required"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Your solution works. I understand the issue well and agree that `map` is not defined as `setup` runs before mounted. There are generally two ways to fix OP's issue: a) prepare the component for the case the prop being unavailable (your solution, more verbose) or b) tell the component explicitely it can rely on the prop being available (my solution). His approach showed he is trying b) with the misspelled required option on the prop definition. Fixing the typo fixed it for me. That the prop is created async in the parent is not part of the question and you are guessing here.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot take back the downvote unless the question is edited.

Comment: Correcting the typo (your "solution" which should be a comment, not an answer) will fix the issue if the parent data is not async. My solution works in all cases.  They are not equal. I won't edit my answer, I just would suggest you refrain from voting on this site if you think creating ONE line of code is verbose, especially if it may be the only correct answer. (I appreciate the willingness to retract the vote though.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a typescript error (TS2532). The type of props is unknown. You need to specify a type for the props parameter, like this:

```
interface Props {
  list: ColumnProps[];
}

setup(props: Props) {
  ...
}
```

Your current props definitions only tell Vue what props and types to expect, but not Typescript

Comment: Seems logic and clean, but then typescript complains on the setup() method with the error `No overload matches this call.ts(2769)`

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from typescript.

This is because of the way vue defines your props for typescript.
If you had `required: true`, then you state it cannot not be undefined, else it may.

The accepted answer is conceptually wrong, but it works because the you check for undefined before accessing the value `if (!props.list) ...` and the compiler is smart enough to know that.

If you know it will be defined and do not want to use `required: true`, you can tell it the compiler by writing `props.list!.map`